# how to set height of UIScrollView properly

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, height, constraints

I have a View. Inside that view I have Scroll view. Inside that Scroll View I have Content View. I set constraint that content view height and width is equal to View's height and width. The problem is that I have Navigation bar above of my superview. So when I look at simulator on running time it gives me extra space of that navigation bar inside UIScrollview. So have can I adjust height of content view.
I want to create constratin like this . Content view height = superview height - 66. 66 is the height of navigation bar...

Comment: the problem: scrollview height  = superview.height + navigationbar.height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the better way is inside your main view put Navigation bar on top of the view and put your Scrollview below the Navigation bar and inside that ScrollView Put the Content View

and if you want to put Navigation bar under the Scrollview you should specify the top space constraint of Content View other wise it will give the same output

Comment: I cant put navigation bar above main view. I made code that works fine. However it doest work the first time veiw load. I need to press button in order make it work . where should i put constraints of view: here is a code: var heightMinusBar = SuperView.frame.height - 66.0
        var constH = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentViewOfScrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: heightMinusBar)
        
        contentViewOfScrollView.addConstraint(constH)

Comment: I put it on viewDidload but it seems not working there.

Comment: just specify constraint of Content View like  top space = below navigation bar

Comment: in that extra space increase twice

Comment: make sure  when you specify constraint  the the constraint to margin box is click

Comment: the problem: scrollview height  = superview.height + navigationbar.height

Comment: check out this question     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967859/ios7-uiscrollview-offset-in-uinavigationcontroller

Comment: refer this it is same as your problem as mention http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192195/uiscrollview-shifts-below-navigation-and-status-bar

Comment: Thanks, Rizwan ! There is now inset now.  I just put this code self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false